# Tryng to Pass a Enum[ ] from Son to Father Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass an Array of Objects(Enums) from a son component to the father. But I'm quite not getting the trick.

Father Component:

```
const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = useState(false);
  const handleReturn = () => filtros;
  const [filtros, setFiltros] = useState<Filtros[]>([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setFiltros(handleReturn);
    console.log(filtros);
  }, [openDialog]);
<FiltrosDialog
        openDialog={openDialog}
        handleCloseDialog={() => setOpenDialog(false)}
        filtrosSelec={filtros}
      />
```

Son Component (there's a lot of code here but trust me, the state is returning an Array of Filtros):

```
interface Props {
  openDialog: boolean;
  handleCloseDialog: () => void;
  filtrosSelec: Filtros[];
}
export enum Filtros {
  Ligacoes = "Ligações",
  Tempo = "Tempo em chamada (min)",
  Email = "E-mails enviados",
  Reuniao = "Reuniões agendadas",
}
const FiltrosDialog: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
  openDialog,
  handleCloseDialog,
  filtrosSelec,
})=> {

const [checked, setChecked] = useState<Filtros[]>([]);
  const [left, setLeft] = useState<Filtros[]>([
    Filtros.Reuniao,
    Filtros.Tempo,
    Filtros.Email,
    Filtros.Ligacoes,
  ]);
  const [right, setRight] = useState<Filtros[]>(filtrosSelec);
  const leftChecked = intersecao(checked, left);
  const rightChecked = intersecao(checked, right);

...}
```

Basically, I'm not sure if my Filtros[] props is supossed to be a function or an array itself...

Answer (score 1):

Your states are fine, but here's the logic for child/parent communication in terms of asking the child to change parent property.

```
  cont Parent = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

    return <Child count={count} change={setCount} />
  }
```

You can see the `setCount` is passed it, not `count`. A child can only change parent property through a method. Because in terms of setting the property, `count = 3` is not going to make it due to that `count` is a primitive value.

This is normally quite clear when you are creating an input component, such as the following.

```
  <Input value={value} onChange={onChange} />
```

Comment: Thanks man! I need to remember that components only communicate like that through functions

Comment: You're welcome, yes, this is the React way, because it requires the `setCount` to schedule a render. Otherwise you could make `count` a pointer, and you can still change it in the child, but that'll be a hack from React perspective.

Comment: Btw, could you accept the answer if you think that solves your problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out how to do it. I need to pass the setState as the function inside the child prop on the parent component. And the child prop need to be a void and its argument is the actual Array:

Parent:

```
const [filtros, setFiltros] = useState<Filtros[]>([]);
...
<FiltrosDialog
        openDialog={openDialog}
        handleCloseDialog={() => setOpenDialog(false)}
        filtrosSelec={setFiltros} />
```

Child:

```
interface Props {
  openDialog: boolean;
  handleCloseDialog: () => void;
  filtrosSelec: (arg: Filtros[]) => void;
}
const FiltrosDialog: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
      openDialog,
      handleCloseDialog,
      filtrosSelec,
    }) => {
const [right, setRight] = useState<Filtros[]>([]);
useEffect(() => filtrosSelec(right));
...
```